# How to make a cycle that takes multiple rasters and mosaics them in R? And save them with an specific name

Tags: r, gis, raster, mosaic, r-modis

I have around of 2000 raster files of different parts of the wolrd. Some of them are from the same day, and other are from different days. I want to mosaic/merge all the files that are from the same day to create "pictures" (rasters) by day.

All the names of the files begins with **"MOD13A3.A2000"** and then *the day of the year the image was captured*, and then other nonimportant stuff. The thing I want to do is to take all the files that start with the same name and merge them.

For example, I would take the first 4 files here, since they begin with **MOD13A3.A2000032...**, merge them and have just one file called **MOD13A3.A2000032**. And then take the other 4 following files, since they begin with **MOD13A3.A2000061...**, merge them and have another file called **MOD13A3.A2000061**.

**MOD13A3.A2000***032*.h12v13.006.2015138123528 //

**MOD13A3.A2000***032*.h13v13.006.2015138123527 //

**MOD13A3.A2000***032*.h13v14.006.2015138123528 //

**MOD13A3.A2000***032*.h14v14.006.2015138123526 //

**MOD13A3.A2000***061*.h12v13.006.2015136111214 //

**MOD13A3.A2000***061*.h13v13.006.2015136111225 //

**MOD13A3.A2000***061*.h13v14.006.2015136111218 //

**MOD13A3.A2000***061*.h14v14.006.2015136111220 //

...

I have been looking into other forums but since I am completely new to R programming I don't understand too much of the codes that are posted. I have thought about making a for cycle that changes the beginning of the file's name, like *"MOD13A3.A2000"+i* but I don't understand the sintaxis of it. I have not been able to find clear examples that show how to change a file's name like this either.

If someone could EXPLAIN a code, I would be SO GRATEFUL!

Answer (score 0):

I would start with `terra` package:

```
library(terra)

r <- list.files(path = "rasters", pattern = "MOD13A3.A2000061.*", full.names = TRUE)
r <- lapply(r, rast)
r <- do.call(merge, r)
```

First line creates list of raster files with specific pattern, 2nd applies `rast()` function to them, and 3rd do `merge`.

Fill free to create a loop for patterns in your filenames: `list.files` reads the files, then take a `substr()` of filenames and find all `unique()` strings.